# During gem update I get permissions error for /usr/bin directory

Tags: ruby, bundler

I get the following when executing sudo gem update:

```
Updating installed gems
Updating actioncable
Fetching actioncable-5.2.3.gem
Fetching actionview-5.2.3.gem
Fetching activesupport-5.2.3.gem
Fetching actionpack-5.2.3.gem
Successfully installed activesupport-5.2.3
Successfully installed actionview-5.2.3
Successfully installed actionpack-5.2.3
Successfully installed actioncable-5.2.3
Parsing documentation for activesupport-5.2.3
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-5.2.3
Installing darkfish documentation for activesupport-5.2.3
Parsing documentation for actionview-5.2.3
Installing ri documentation for actionview-5.2.3
Installing darkfish documentation for actionview-5.2.3

..... many more successful lines ......

Fetching bundler-2.0.2.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

Not sure what else to try except the sudo that I am using.

I expect the update to complete without failing.

Comment: Use RVM or rbenv and forget sudo with `bundler`/`gem`.

Comment: can you please update your question to include the output of `gem env` ? But perhaps also see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly recommended to use a ruby version manager so you never have to mess with trying to update system ruby i.e. avoid `sudo gem update`

These are widely used in the ruby community.

https://rvm.io/rvm/install

https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

If you have installed a version manager, than it's likely something wrong with your $PATH variable.  See my comment on your question.